Traefik 2.11 file provider fails with ReadDirectoryChanges error
While upgrading my Docker setup from Traefik v2.9 to v2.11 I started to see the following error message:

Cannot start the provider *file.Provider: error adding file watcher: ReadDirectoryChanges: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

Any idea on how to get around this error?

The issue appears to be a defect in Traefik. I've reported an issue here.
As a workaround you can update the command for Traefik in the docker-compose.yml to disable the watcher:
- "--providers.file.directory=C:/etc/traefik/config/dynamic/"
- "--providers.file.watch=false"

